# Should all controls in a complex software inherit from a self written interface

Tags: c#, wpf, controls, abstract-class, platform-independent

Is it a good idea, to create an interface for the most controls which should be used in a complex software (wirtten with c#/wpf)? Currently we have the problem, that we use controls from Microsoft and some third party companies. Our problem is, that if we want to change some third party components, we don't want to change the howle software, because we do a lot of customizing for our customer.

So it is a good idea, to create an abstract class for every control we use, and only use the member the abstract class/interface provides?

Maybe this is a bad solution for some reasons, and i don't get it.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very deep question but I will try to give you a response.

I would start by saying that it is very good to separate the presentation logic from UI controls. Generally, you should peek a design pattern derived from MVP or use the current trend pattern, the so called "presentation model" invented by Martin Fowler.

I highly recommend to read every information about software design and best practices. A good start would be to read everything here: http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/OrganizingPresentations.html

From my experience, the best gain of doing a separation between UI and presentation logic is not changing UI technology but rather gives you the freedom to test very easy your presentation logic. In my entire career I never switched to another UI controls provider.

So, have in mind TESTABILITY not changing UI technology.

Talking about patterns, in WPF (you said that you use WPF) there is already a presentation logic pattern used => the so called MVVM wich is not something fancy but the old Presentation Model in a rebranded clothes.

Related to how you think about your problem... the aproach that you are describing is more related to the "Model-View-Presenter" pattern, more exactly the passive-view subpattern in wich controls are abstracted to the presentation logic using interfaces. The state is present in UI and the logic in presenter. This is contrary to the Presentation Model pattern in wich the state is in presenter and the logic also there.

I think you should NOT make a cocktail of presentation patterns in your application and my advice would be: Let MVVM as your base pattern and try to use it corectly. Testability will be enhanced by this pattern and I don't think that you will ever need to change UI technology in your case. But even if you will change it, if you coded corectly on MVVM pattern the change will be doable.

Comment: With MWWM, do you mean MVVM? Thank you for your complex and great answer. Currently we use the MVVM patter (UI - ViewModel - Controller/EF)

Comment: @BendEg Yes, i corrected that. Thank you for telling me.